# How to translate "给力" in English?

Tags: translation, simplified-characters

The word 给力 is often used on Chinese social networks. What is the correct meaning of it in English?

Comment: It means "awesome". But as it is now accepted on the Internet, you can use [gelivable](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=gelivable) or [geilivable](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=geilivable) in informal cases.

Comment: The one word invented exclusively for 给力 is Gelievable

Comment: Your question doesn't explain clearly why you don't understand this phrase. There are already many sites which provide a thorough explanation of this phrase. We only accept translation requests on this site if you have a particular problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means `awesome`. All English translations for 给力 at mdbg.net: `cool, nifty, awesome, impressive, to put in extra effort`
http://www.mdbg.net/chindict/chindict.php?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=geili

The word has also found it's way into English slang in the form of `geilivable` 
http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=geilivable

Geilivable is not very common in western countries though, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

When people want to express a very extraordinary thing, but can not find the apposite words. People usually us `给力`. It comes from Northeast dialect. You can translate it as FANTASTIC ect. In short, it is to express your surprise emotions. For more information,you can send Email to lzy785@163.com

Comment: Welcome to Chinese SE @user4018. The idea is to keep all the information publicly available here. If the person who posted the question have further questions related to your answer he/she can post comments here. You can then edit your answer to make it more clear. No need to be apologetic for bad English. Others can suggest improvements to your answer. For example improve the language.

Answer (score 0):

给力 is mostly used for the "to put in extra effort" meaning. Like in football, if Germany is not doing well, “不给力啊，德国。” Or if Spain is putting in a lot of effort, “西班牙太给力了。”